# Enable CORS on CRM365 (on-premises)

Tags: javascript, cors, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

I would like to retrieve data from a Microsoft Dynamics CRM 365 site which is not available online (i.e. via Azure AD) from a single page web application using JavaScript.
But all the requests to the CRM server are blocked by the browser as the CRM server does not send the correct CORS headers allowing my webserver to retrieve data.
There are tutorials available explaining how to connect using Azure, but they don't apply in my environment.

(Just statically sending `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is probably not enough as I need to authenticate and using a wildcard is not supported when using authentication afaik.)

Is there a way to use CORS with a local CRM 365?

Comment: `my webserver` ... a web**server** making requests to another server doesn't need CORS headers

Comment: I am sorry for not being precise. It's a JavaScript running locally in the browser in a single page application that wants to retrieve data from the CRM server.

Comment: So, you have two servers - one which you're trying to configure CORS on, and the other server the page that requires CORS ... how about you proxy the request from that server to the CRM365 one - that way, CORS will never be an issue

Comment: This question is being [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420131).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of trying and some help from other websites, I think I found the solution:

Dynamics CRM 365 does not care about the CORS issue, nor does it add the necessary headers for people who need them for their requests.

In order to get the headers, they have to be added at web server (IIS) level using the `HTTP Response Headers` or be added to the `web.config` file in the website's directory on the file sytem.

If authentication is needed on the Dynamics CRM system, the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is not allowed to have the value `*` (wildcard). The value of this header needs to match the calling server's URL, which means that the web server has to dynamically change the header value for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` depending on the calling server's host name. (I found this information on https://kamranicus.com/cors-multiple-origins-iis/)

You also need to add the header `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` and set its value to `true` for Authentication to work properly.

If you need to send additional headers to the CRM system with the request, you need to add those headers to the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header in order to tell the client browser which headers are allowed to be sent along with the request.

Here's what I have now and what's working on my end:

```
   <configuration>
     ...
     <location>
       <system.webServer>
         ...
         <httpPrococol>
           <customHeaders>
             <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
             <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Authorization, Prefer" />
             <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
           </customHeaders>
         </httpProtocol>
         <rewrite>
           <outboundRules>
             ...
             <rule name="AddCrossDomainHeader">
               <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Access_Control_Allow_Origin" pattern=".*" />
               <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                 <add input="{HTTP_ORIGIN}" pattern="(http(s)?:\/\/((.+\.)?mydomain\.com))" />
               </conditions>
               <action type="Rewrite" value="{C:0}" />
             </rule>           
           </outboundRules>
         </rewrite>
       </system.webServer>
     </location>
     ...
   </configuration>
```

I hope that this also helps others having the same problems as I had.

Comment: Hi and thanks for sharing your solution. I have the same requirements and I have added the required response headers for my website to the CRM system in IIS. The problem is that my CRM system adds a wild card `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header when my website sends request and therefore the browser throws this error: `The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, http://mysite.mynet.com', but only one is allowed.` http://mysite.mynet.com is the header I have added but I don't know where the wild card one comes from and it is why added. Any idea?

Comment: It would be easier if you shared what you have in your IIS configuration. I thought the headers were added by IIS and not by CRM, but I am not sure either...

Comment: As I have stated above, I have added the response header for my website in IIS configuration of my dynamics 365 website. In other words, in my dynamics 365 website in IIS, I have added this response header: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with the value: `https://mysite.mynet.com`. But I get this error when my website tries to call dynamics, that the response header contains multiple values, which is correct - I can see in the developer tools in the browser that the response header from the call contains two values. But I have only added one. I don't know where the wild card comes form.

Answer (score -6):

As you said you only need local solution I would suggest using CORS proxy server to bypass the CORS. https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-cors-proxy . Is it possible to turn offf authentification as well ? Instead of a wildcard you can specify localhost ip adress.

```
req.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'false');
req.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
req.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
req.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "*");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, doku. Unfortunately, it is not possible to turn off authentication on the server.
And I need multiple people to access the data on different client PCs. By "local" I meant "not cloud". The web site is still running on a web server in my company environment and the CRM system is running in the same company environment on another host. (btw. I did not downvote your answer)